# UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character upon running a PyInstaller-compiled script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've just finished a program I've been working on and have been wanting to compile it to a single .exe file for distribution. I decided to use pyinstaller 3 as it has worked for me before however upon successfully compiling my file I get the following message upon running the program.

```
C:\Users\Luke\Documents\program\dist>viewbot.exe
_ctypes
C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI59042\_ctypes.pyd
_tkinter
C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI59042\_tkinter.pyd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\program\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 302, in load_module
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Documents\program\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 474, in load_module
UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character
```

If it helps, this is a minimal code example of my program:

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
call("color a", shell=True)
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
print ("Please locate your firefox browser)")
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title="Please locate your firefox browser")
path = path + " {0}"
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
viewed = 0
url = "http://google.com"
refresh = 15
views = 5
call("cls", shell=True)
for i in range(views):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(path.format(url))
    time.sleep(refresh)
    viewed = viewed + 1
    print ("Viewed", viewed, "time")
    proc.terminate()
    call("cls", shell=True)
print ("Viewing finished in", refresh * views, "seconds")
time.sleep(5)
```

Not quite sure what to do here so any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Do you see the error if you run your script without PyInstaller? [Create a minimal code example that shows your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e.g., if the whole script is just `import tkinter`; does it work? Unrelated: it is `mbcs`, not `mbca`.

Comment: My guess is you have a BOM at the start of the file.

Comment: Don't post text as an image. Copy-paste it instead.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian The script runs smoothly without Pyinstaller, [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Gk0rUGJH) is a minimal example of my code which runs fine before Pyinstaller compilation. It views google 5 times at 15 second intervals using firefox.

Comment: @ivan-pozdeev What do you mean by BOM? And sorry I couldn't copy-paste the text from terminal, it disappears after a second making it difficult to copy-paste anything from it.

Comment: *"if the whole script is just `import tkinter`; does it work?"* (if compiled using PyInstaller). [edit] your question, don't put the necessary info on off-site resources. To capture console messages: open the console (run `cmd`), run your script from within the console.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian Thanks, just edited the question with the new info. Just tried compiling 'import tkinter' and it ran without any errors.

Comment: @Luke25361: good. Now, you have a code example that does work (`import tkinter`) and a code example that does not work (your current full code): try to a create a minimal example that does not work ([remove various fragments from your code until it starts working, or add various fragments to `import tkinter` until it stops working](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) -- I would try to remove all `subprocess` calls first and/or create a *minimal* program that uses `filedialog.askopenfilename()`. Use `@` autocomplete if you want me to be notified about your comments.

Comment: @j-f-sebastian Ok, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'll get back with what was causing it to create that error once finished.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message.  I fixed it by replacing `\` by `\\` in the string containing the path of the file to open.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! What do you mean by the string containing the path to the file to import?

Comment: I had the same error as yours, but in a different use case without pyinstaller.  I was trying to import a csv file into pandas.  Initially, I thought that the problem was in the csv file, but eventually I found out that it was in the path of the file.  Using \\ fixed it.  Not sure how it applies in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think another elegent way is to combine the `pd.read_csv` with the `open` function. For instance, if I have a csv file called `Ürümqi Diwopu International Airport.csv`, I could use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv(open(os.path.join(datapath, "Ürümqi Diwopu International Airport.csv"), 'r', encoding='utf-8'), index_col=0)
```

Hope this could help~

Comment: Thanks,  this solved my issue too for Turkish..  Setting encoding in pandas.read_csv has no effect in filename it does effect file contents only. Example filename : "SomeTurkish_ParçaŞĞİL\dataset_csv.csv" .