# Pandas read_table errors

Tags: python, pandas, text

I'm new to Python and trying to learn Pandas but running into a problem earlly on. I'm trying to read a log file and save it as a dataframe. It's a space delimited text file with a single header row containing the column names. Here's the sample code I'm running just to test the read function.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_table('C:\Aerosonde Test Logs\MH_Data\TEC_20170105-083220\222_1_4435_.log',
               delim_whitespace='True', nrows=20)
print(data)
```

Below is a snippet of the log file.

```
<Clock>[ms] <Year>  <Month> <Day>   <Hours> <Minutes>   <Seconds>   <Lat>[rad]  <Lon>[rad]  <Height>[m]
48161   2017    1   5   4   30  13.366  5.02E-06    8.05E-07    267.37
49161   2017    1   5   4   30  14.366  5.01E-06    7.95E-07    266.61
50161   2017    1   5   4   30  15.366  5.02E-06    7.95E-07    266.24
```

I keep getting errors though.  When I try and read the entire log file I'm getting the error.

> "UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character"

I tried opening the log file in Excel and then saving it again as a tab delimited file. When I tried to open that file using the same code I got a seperate error.

> "TypeError: an integer is required"

I tried skipping the header rows thinking the extra characters there were the problem but that didn't fix it either. So now I'm at a loss and hoping for some advice!

EDIT: So thanks to Matteo I was able to fix the UnicodeEncodeError by adding '\' to the filepath string.  Now though I get the TypeError: an integer is required when trying to open the log file.  I appear to get it when trying to open any space or tab delimeted file. I just made a quick space delimeted file and I get the same error. I even looked at the data in a hex editor to double check and I don't see any odd bytes so no idea whats happening.

Current read table code

```
data = pd.read_table('C:\\Aerosonde Test Logs\\MH_Data\\TEC_20170105-083220\\TestLogFile.txt',
               delim_whitespace='True')
```

[HexData for test text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzl7B.png)

Comment: Just FYI - I copy and pasted the data you provided into a text editor (vim in my case), saved it as a csv, and opened it in pandas without any problem. I'm running pandas 0.19.1.

Comment: I'd copied that data from excel so the specific bytes are not the same as the raw log file.  For what it's worth I just tried opening up the raw log file in excel and save it as csv and then was able to open it with read_csv without errors. I guess this means there's an issue with the delimiter?

Comment: Not sure - sounds like there is something funky going on with the file format and encoder for the excel version that is preventing it from being read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matteo Franchi fixed the UnicodeEncodeError by advising that I add an additional '\' to the filepath string which still left me with the TypeError when I tried to read in the data.  Apparently I was not specifying the delim_whitespace correctly.  I had copied that argument from an example where the True statement was inside of quotes and that does not work.  The code below worked fine.

```
data = pd.read_table('C:\\Aerosonde Test Logs\\MH_Data\\TEC_20170105-083220\\222_1_4435_.log',
                 delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I thinks that the error is due to the string of the path of log file; you can try to put \ instead of . 
See also [UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character upon running a PyInstaller-compiled script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173736/unicodeencodeerror-mbcs-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-0-1-inval)

Comment: So adding the \ to the path string did seem to work and now I am not getting the UnicodeEncodeError!  So that's one step done!  Unfortunately I am still getting the "TypeError: an integer is required".  As stated in my other reply if I open the file in Excel and save as CSV then I can open the file with Read_csv with no error but this does not work when I save it as a tab delimeted file and read_table.  I'm guessing this means there's an error with how I'm calling out the delimeter or maybe in the log file itself?

Comment: Thanks . It helped.

Comment: Make sure too if the path name is alphabert character